# CUDA Visual Profiler 5.0 doesn't generate timeline, Eror with Cudadevicereset()

Tags: c++, cuda

I use CUDA Visual Profiler do analyze my CUDA project, but it message

> "Unable to read the entire session timeline. the displayed timeline may be empty or incomplete because the application aborted or failed to flush profile data before exiting. The application should call cudaDeviceReset() to ensure that all profile data is flushed. "

How to I call cudaDeviceReset() , VS 2012 happen error when I call it in the end of project. What libary, methods or parameter that I need ?

Answer (score 2):

You [call it like this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gdcc2c6f914eb9461565b12648faa5e28):

```
cudaDeviceReset();
```

Assuming you are compiling your project with `nvcc` (i.e. it is a CUDA project, in a `.cu` file), then no libraries, methods, or parameters are needed.

If your project is a C++ project (`.cpp` file) then you will need to add

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

to your source code, and you will need to add the appropriate path to the CUDA include files to the compiler specification, and the appropriate path to the CUDA libraries to the linker specification.  These paths can be discovered for your specific Visual Studio installation by reviewing some of the sample projects.

By the way, visual studio 2012 is not an officially supported environment for CUDA 5.0.  You can discover this by reviewing the file `CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.pdf` (use windows file explorer find function to locate that file on your machine.)

Comment: Oh sorry Robert, in my project had `#include < cuda_runtime.h >` previous - When I build, It's Error with `cudaDeviceReset()`. **But when I delete `#include < cuda_runtime.h >` and type again, It work.** It may be the fault of VS ?

Comment: What error specifically are you getting with `cudaDeviceReset()` ?  Perhaps you should copy the text of the error into your question.

Comment: **`error C3861: 'cudaDeviceReset': identifier not found`**.Althought I have **<cuda_runtime.h>**, it have an error.But when I delete **< cuda_runtime.h >** and type again, It work. Thanks for your enthusiasm !

Comment: I'm unable to explain that.  Your question is missing a lot of detail. Providing a complete file including the filename and the command used to compile it, as well as the complete output (which can be captured from the VS console output window) might help.